# Which org best represents the Summer '19 GA orgs?

Tags: sharing, scratch-org, preview

We have a Summer '19 preview org (https://gs0.salesforce.com) created on 5/31/2019 and a scratch org (https://drive-momentum-6799-dev-ed.cs67.my.salesforce.com) created on 5/30/2019. They differ in two ways:

- Some code running inside a Site that *queries* a hierarchical custom setting under `with sharing` works - returns a row in the former - but fails - returns no rows in the latter (probably relating to [Enable External Org-Wide Defaults in Orgs with Communities or Portals (Critical Update, Enforced)](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_networks_owd_cruc_enforced.htm))
- The "Sharing Settings" UI differs between the two orgs - screenshots below

**Which of these orgs better represents the GA product?** I care, because if it is the latter org, then we will need to work on a fix ASAP.

Preview org:

[image: preview org]

Scratch org:

[image: sratch org]

Comment: Is community enabled in scratch org?

Comment: No it isn't - explains the UI difference I presume?

Comment: Correction: communities are enabled in the scratch org but are not enabled in the preview org.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe those screen shots' labels are switched? Looking at a couple orgs & SBs, activation of communities seems to be the driver of whether or not those User Visibility and Other Settings options are avail. ie, I see them if Communities is on. In a prod org w/o the critical update activated, they appeared when I turned communities on.

Comment: I also think those settings & that update are a red herring. Custom Settings don't have sharing - they're either Public and thus readable by all profiles, or Protected and only readable by code in their managed package. Are you querying with SOQL, or using one of the Apex methods? And not to be insulting, the record is def there?

Comment: Hi @ThomasTaylor, the code is querying not using the normal hierarchical custom setting API; changing the accessing class from `with sharing` to `without sharing` avoids the problem. Yes, I agree it is unexpected and sharing normally has no effect on custom settings.

Comment: Interesting - can you test with one of the API methods and see if that makes a difference? Seems like a possible bug and a support case is the right route. Is this a Public setting outside of a managed package? Just curious to try and reproduce.